# Jython missing functions in sys module

Tags: java, python

I have an python script which I need to run in my java application. I tried to execute it from jython but I have strange problem:

`from sys import getdlopenflags`

I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name getdlopenflags`

When I try to check contents of sys:

`import sys`

`dir(sys)`

the output is:

`['JYTHON_DEV_JAR', 'JYTHON_JAR', 'PYTHON_CACHEDIR', 'PYTHON_CACHEDIR_SKIP', 'PYTHON_CONSOLE_ENCODING', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__displayhook__', '__excepthook__', '__findattr_ex__', '__name__', '__new__', '__rawdir__', '__setattr__', '__stderr__', '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_getframe', '_jy_interpreter', '_systemRestart', 'add_classdir', 'add_extdir', 'add_package', 'argv', 'builtin_module_names', 'builtins', 'byteorder', 'classDictInit', 'classLoader', 'cleanup', 'copyright', 'currentWorkingDir', 'defaultencoding', 'determinePlatform', 'displayhook', 'doInitialize', 'exc_clear', 'exc_info', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 'executable', 'exit', 'filesystemencoding', 'getBaseProperties', 'getBuiltin', 'getBuiltins', 'getClassLoader', 'getCurrentWorkingDir', 'getDefaultBuiltins', 'getPath', 'getPathLazy', 'getPlatform', 'getWarnoptions', 'getdefaultencoding', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getrecursionlimit', 'hexversion', 'initialize', 'isPackageCacheEnabled', 'last_traceback', 'last_type', 'last_value', 'maxint', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'minint', 'modules', 'packageManager', 'path', 'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'ps1', 'ps2', 'recursionlimit', 'registerCloser', 'registry', 'setBuiltins', 'setClassLoader', 'setCurrentWorkingDir', 'setPlatform', 'setWarnoptions', 'setprofile', 'setrecursionlimit', 'settrace', 'shadow', 'stderr', 'stdin', 'stdout', 'subversion', 'toString', 'unregisterCloser', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions']`

obviously getdlopenflags is missing. Is it possible to use this function in jython (I have the newest - 2.5.2) According to the documentation on the http://jython.org/docs/library/sys.html the sys.getdlopenflags is present.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

It says "Availability: Unix" in the documentation. The Jython docs seem to have copied that unchanged from the CPython docs. So this function is only available on a Unix installation. Possibly Jython doesn't have it at all - I don't know Java well enough, but since it's supposedly platform-independent, it can't support system-specific functions.

Comment: Java kind of constitutes a distinct platform for Python (in fact, os.name returns "Java" in Jython, I think), and getdlopenflags in particular makes no sense in the context of the Java platform -- there is no "dlopen" call.